# conditional logit for panel data in python

Tags: python

I am trying to estimate a logit model with individual fixed effects in a panel data setting, i.e. a conditional logit model, with python.

I have found the pylogit library. However, the documentation I could find, explained how to use the conditional logit model for multinomial models with varying choice attributes. This model does not seem to be the same use case as a simple binary panel model.

So my questions are:

Does pylogit allow to estimate conditional logits for panel data?

If so, is there documentation?

If not, are there other libraries that allow you to estimate this type of model?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

I'm the creator of pylogit.

I don't have built in utilities for estimating conditional logits with fixed effects. However, you can use pylogit to estimate this model. Simply

1. Create dummy variables for each decision maker. Be sure to leave out one decision maker for identification.
2. For each created dummy variable, add dummy variable's column name to the one's utility specification.

Comment: Hi Timothy, I came across pylogit recently and faced a similar dilemma as OP. I have a panel dataset for which I'd like to run a logistic regression with both country and year fixed effects. To my understanding, adding in dummies for countries and years into a logit specification and then estimating using MLE is not equivalent to estimating a conditional logit model. Is that right? My follow-up would then be: which pylogit function would you suggest I use for my particular scenario (panel logit w/ fixed effects). I appreciate any feedback, thanks so much

Comment: Hey Kenneth, the only thing that makes a conditional logit, conditional, is that there are explanatory variables that are "conditional" on the alternative instead of on the decision maker. For instance, travel time that takes on a different value for bicycles versus cars. See for instance, the abstract here: https://link.springer.com/article/10.2307/2061541

Either way, to estimate a panel logit with fixed effects, I'd still follow the two steps I posted above.

Comment: Thank you Timothy, very helpful! One last question: for ridge regression in a mixed logit model, does your package take the sum of squares of the means and standard deviations of each normal distribution for each randomized coefficient? Or does the penalty term also include any fixed (non-random) coefficients that may be included in the specification? I'm having trouble understanding how ridge works in the mixed logit model from the .py files.

Comment: For ridge regression, pylogit uses the sum of squares of all parameters in the model: means, standard deviations, and the non-random coefficients.

Comment: if you are using `formula`, just add `C(unit_id)` in your equation, this is the equivalent of Stata's `i.unit_id`. But it would really be great to have a fixed effect option in this or other python packages that provide a discrete choice model estimation as adding dummy could lead to the `singular matrix` problem when you have a large N (say 10,000,000) and small T (say 2)  panel.

Comment: I do not know very much theoretical detail of choice model, but based on my testing on Stata, running `clogit` and `xtlogit`  with individual fixed effect will produce different result compared to running `logit` with individual dummy explicitly (base group created).